# Clear textbox when tap RFID card?

Tags: c#, winforms, rfid

I got 2 RFID cards, with different values e.g 123 and 456.
When I click on `textbox1`, and then tap the first card into a machine, the `textbox1.text` will give me a text of 123.

The question is how can I clear the first card value when I tap the second card to machone. what event on the `textbox1` should I use, so when I tap the second card it only give me 456.

The code which the device sends has a specific lengths, for example 10 characters.

Currently using the code which I have tried, after I tap the the first card, and then tap the second card, the `textbox1.text` become 123456, while I expect it to show 123 for first card and 456 for second card.

```
private void textEdit1_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text1;
    text1 = textEdit1.Text;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text1)) return;

    if (text1.Length == 10)
    {              
        getcodestudent(text1);
        textEdit1.Text = string.Empty;
        textEdit2.Focus();
        textEdit1.Focus();
        cektap();
        if (tap == 0 && tap2 == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("member not registered on this class");
        }
    }            
}
```

When I debug it. The event run twice, because I set the `textedit.Text` to empty it ran over (loop) 1 times.  conclusion :
When I debug the program, after it reach the end of code `messagebox.show` it loop back to `textEdit1.Text = string.Empty;` and again run the cektap() method. only loop once.

Comment: Wild guess, but in case you're doing something like: `textbox1.text += textbox2.text;` replace that by `textbox1.text = textbox2.text`

Comment: iam still not using any code yet.

Comment: Then could you describe your setup a little more? For example, whose code are you using, or what libraries, or anything to go on so that I can help you modify some code somewhere.

Comment: iam still not using anycode yet. and doesnt have any libraries. the machine just simple read a number when i tap on the machine (usb portable). e.g when i open a notepad and i tap on it, its just give me an output of number in notepad

Comment: @KeyurPATEL well, iam currently iam using that code. but it ran twice

Comment: At the start of the function, add `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text1)) return;` after the `text1 = textEdit1.Text;`. `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` returns true if the string is null or empty.

Comment: is it necessay to put `if (text1.Length == 10)` because when run it. it input the value one by one. (when i debug it, it give 1 then 12 then 123) is it really like that when i tap a card?

Comment: What's the length of code which is sent by those cards? And is it always the same length?

Comment: `textEdit1_EditValueChanged` From the name, I can guess that it fires _every time the textbox value changes_. And I also assume the code is inputted letter by letter rather than all at once. You can add another check in addition to the `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` such as `if (text1.Length != *the length you know it will be*)` return;` in order to stop it from running the code every time. Other than that, I don't see any other way to stop the function from running multiple times (it is probably something you cannot modify)

Comment: yes, always the same , 10 digit. i have tried added your code, it still ran twice, after i added some method or function.. it give me `messagebox("member not registered")` twice.. do you mind to check it?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL yes, thats why if theres any other kind of event or logic to prevent it

Comment: Could you try to use that in editor? Normally, these kind of device will send a special character after the data (e.g. enter). if that the case, you only need to check that key

Comment: @Alex maybe i was using a wrong event. i''try on event keypress. because as reza said it usually send key strokes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bar-code scanners or such devices usually send key strokes. So you can handle `KeyPress` event of `TextBox` and check if the length of `Text` is the specific length which you expect, then clear the `Text`:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.textBox1.TextLength == 10)
        this.textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Also some devices send an extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> key at the end of sequence which can be handled and be used to run default action of Form or changing focus or something else. For example:

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        //Do Something and the select all texts to prepare text box for next card
        this.textBox1.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: mmh, thank for your information. totally new in rfid. i will to put some code in keypress then rather then edit value.

Comment: Also some devices send an extra `Enter` key at the end of sequence which can be handled and be used to run default action of `Form` or changing focus or something else.

Comment: i want to ask one more thing.. when i tap the card, is key stroke was pressed one by one ? e.g 1 then 12 then 123 then 1234 then 12345 and so on.

Comment: You can test it. But as far as I know, keystrokes are sent like normal keyboard strokes one by one.

Comment: yes, it was one by one. i thought it was inputed all digit rather than one by one, so i dont have to put the limit of text.length ==10. oh when i open a notepad and tap on it, it input all digit but give extra `enter` does it count ? and affect on your code?

Comment: If you use a simple `TextBox` control, you don't need to change my code. It will work properly. Also as I said, you can use that extra Enter character for other purposes.

Comment: well, it work properly. for extra enter can you give me an example of other purposes?

Comment: done. before i cant click on it. because of reputation

Comment: About the `Enter` for example if you have a `Button1` on your `Form` which you set it as `AcceptButton` of `Form`, then after receiving the `Enter` key, the code which you have written in `Click` event of `Button1` will be executed.

Comment: can you take a look the other problem when i use your code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39652317/when-tap-only-get-1-digit