# when tap only get 1 digit

Tags: c#, winforms, rfid

for my rfid card value was

[image: rfidno]

the case is when i tap why the text was not empty ? and when i tap the second card it only give me 1 digit

[image: tapcard1]

card2 tap

[image: tapcard2]

the code i use

```
 private void textEdit1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.textEdit1.Text.Length == 10)
        {
            getcodestudent();
            this.textEdit1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

for getcodestudent()

```
  public void getcodestudent()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlParameter para2 = new SqlParameter();
        try
        {
            ds6.Clear();
            dt6.Clear();

            command6.Connection = myConnection;
            command6.CommandText = //..//;                               
            adapter.SelectCommand = command6;
            adapter.Fill(ds6);
            adapter.Fill(dt6);                               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error" + ex);

        }
        if (dt6.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            member = ds6.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(member);
        }
```

but if i delete the text after tapping with card with `backspace` and then tap again with card, it works perfectly fine on running `getcodestudent();`            `this.textEdit1.Text = "";`

Comment: What's `getcodestudent();`? Does the problem exists also if you comment that code?

Comment: if i comment it. when the first time i tap, the textbox.text give me 2834978283 but it didnt clear the text. but when i tap other card it become null..

Comment: for case2 when i use `getcodestudent()` after i tap twice which give me only 1 digit but when i delete it manually with backspace and  when i tap it again, it works perfectly fine with `getcodestudent()` also with `text = " "`.

Comment: Please include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.  take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, i have modified it

Comment: Use a breakpoint in the event to see what's happening. Also try using an standard `TextBox` instead of that `TextEdit` control.

Comment: Also calling `getcodestudent();` after checking `if (this.textEdit1.Text.Length == 10)` is not correct decision. It executes only after you tap another card. You should execute that method immediately after reading the value from the first card. To do so you can use that Enter key which is sent at the end of sequence.

Comment: I'd highly suggest you start using variable names that are descriptive; it's unclear what your code is supposed to be doing if you have names like `ds6`, `dt6`, `textEdit1`, and `para2`

Comment: @chopperfield Take a look at the sample in your previous question about Enter key.

Comment: @RezaAghaei when i use breakpoint. the text.length only stop at 9 and then continue to the program, but when i delete 1 digit, it bring back to the code the text.length was 10 and start do a function in side `if`

Comment: @chopperfield read my previous comment and try handling `Enter` key. Also I guess your problem is because of `TextEdit` control, it may have different behavior on its event rather that a `TextBox`. Try using a `TextBox` instead. My answers has been posted based on `TextBox`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei tried it. its same how to handling enter key ?

Comment: @chopperfield Like did in answer of your previous question.